# ZFS which uses SAN (ISCSI/FC/NVMEoe...) as VDEV

Tags: zfs

**Is it reasonable to use ISCSI/FC as a block device and use it as a vdev for ZFS?**

Reasoning:

There is only so much disks (even with external enclosures) that you can put in one host. We are looking into a solution where we would build a head unit (server acting as iSCSI initiator) and disk hosts (servers acting as iSCSI targets). Disk hosts would expose their disks (either each one individually or RAID-ed), head unit would connect over ethernet to those disk units over iSCSI and use those exported disks as VDEVs for a giant ZFS. Remember, Z in ZFS means Zettabyte! Meaningless if you cannot connect a zettabyte worth of disks somehow :)

Comment: _"So in the end, I picked ZFS for the simplest of reasons: it sounds cool."_ from [Jeff Bonwick's Blog](https://archive.wikiwix.com/cache/index2.php?url=https%253A%252F%252Fblogs.oracle.com%252Fbonwick%252Fen_US%252Fentry%252Fyou_say_zeta_i_say#federation=archive.wikiwix.com&tab=url) (-;

Answer (score 0):

Sounds doable, but once you leave "a bunch of disks" and go for "Petabyte-scale", you might fare much better with something that does a bit more management for you. Because while ZFS will beautifully build a volume out of your iSCSI servers, things like "We need to shut them down in a safe manner", "we have roughly 2000 disks, which ones are nearing their end of life", and things beyond zRAID, which become more efficient very quickly more efficient and/or reliable for larger arrays, are not covered by ZFS.

I don't know how many machines as how many disks you need to connect, and what reliability, hot-swappability (if you have many disks,*one* will eventually fail, wht then?) you need. If this is "large": Sounds like a job for a Ceph cluster. Ceph is what you want for storage cluster.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do have a lot of experience dealing with ZFS and I just wondered if anyone has gone that route in production.

Comment: I see people run ZFS *on* Ceph-supplied block devices, so yes, that does happen. I've not seen "rack sized" disk arrays being directly done with ZFS, but then again, I'm not really a storage server person. It's just that it strikes me as preferable to have a) distributed error control, i.e., not having to have redundancy in each computer, but being able to correct the failure of one disk in node A with data from nodes B, C,…M and b) having an appropriate amount of management in each node, so that things like swapping drives doesn't mean the operator of the file system has to care and

Comment: c) not using a single-point of failure central computer that builds the ZFS volume from all the storage .Thing here is, you're building a many-moving-parts, high-reliability system. So, you want each part to be hot-swappable, at any time, ideally with the option of a hot spare already running to take over. That all would point towards starting from some large size, "just" ZFS is a bit underequipped.

Comment: You are correct, once you build a head unit and two disk nodes, you already have three servers. Might as well turn them into Ceph cluster.